# Decrypt upper_bound with reverse_iterator stl error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl

What exactly did compiler means by this:

> ```
> c:\usr\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:
> In function 
> '_FIter std::upper_bound(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&)
> [
>   with _FIter = std::reverse_iterator<
>     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ModelItem*, std::vector<ModelItem> > >,
>     _Tp = Model::close_active(int)::<lambda(const t_item&)>
> ]':
>
> model.cpp:58:3:   instantiated from here
>
>
> c:\usr\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2461:4:
>
> error: no match for 'operator<' in
> '__val < __middle.std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::operator*
>
> [
>   with _Iterator =
>     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ModelItem*, std::vector<ModelItem> >,
>      std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::reference = ModelItem&
> ]()'
> ```

For this peace of code:

```
t_itemlist::reverse_iterator rit = std::upper_bound(
  m_itemlist.rbegin(), m_itemlist.rend(),
  [&at](const t_item& item){ return item.at > at; }
);
```

I'd like to use reverse iterators.

(SO form ask me add more details with text as the question is too more code for its opinion. But I do not know what to say more.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 paramter version of [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) doesn't expect a comparison function but the desired value as its third parameters.

The comparison function must have two parameters as it replaces `operator<` which is a binary operator.

A wild guess:

```
auto rit = std::upper_bound(m_itemlist.rbegin(), m_itemlist.rend(), at,
    [](auto const& at, auto const& item) { return at < item.at; });
```

Comment: Thanks, seems I also missed the `value` param for `upper_bound`.